# How can I add my free font to Ubuntu repositories?

Tags: package-management, fonts

How can I can share my freeware font with Ubuntu users?

Is there a way to make a package, or change an existing package to include the font I've designed?

Here is a gzipped archive with the font:  [Labiryntowy_pl.tgz](http://alfabetozdobny.appspot.com/images/Labiryntowy_pl.tgz)

It includes a rendering of font output to pdf, as well as the .ttf file:

Here is part of the description (translated from Polish via Google):

> Font Labiryntowy_pl created as a practical realization of the idea of
>   ​​the alphabet labyrinth. This font contains over 300 ligatures and
>   most of the characters needed to complete the titles and monograms.
>
> Latest version font: 1.52 The latest version on the [website](http://alfabetozdobny.appspot.com/?str=labiryntowy) .
>
> Font is released under freeware license. (c) Copyright by Jacek
>   Szewczyk A.D. 2008-2012

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Consider rephrasing your question as its not 100% clear what you're asking here.

Comment: Looks awesome....  I've edited the question to make it more clear what you are interested in.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to create a package and submit this package for inclusion in Ubuntu.

The Ubuntu developer site has a page [Packaging New Software](http://developer.ubuntu.com/packaging/html/packaging-new-software.html) with all this information in a nice overview. It explains:

- Starting a Package
- Building the package
- Submitting for inclusion

Also consider submitting this to Debian as Ubuntu (and a lot more distributions) is based on that, you'll reach an even bigger audience.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to release it under an open license, such as [SIL Open Font License](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIL_Open_Font_License). Freeware things are not accepted by Debian's (nor Ubuntu's) repositories--everything must be [free software](http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.html).